# How do global cancel/exit commands work in bash?

Tags: ruby, bash

As I have done multiple times before, I've written bash scripts, and just general commands that go nowhere.  They just blink the little command line cursor at me for infinity until I control+C the command.  When I do cancel the command, what exactly is going on when I do this? Am I somehow stopping and killing the current PID I'm working on?  Does it jump to a different run-level and execute something to terminate the command?

On a slightly different note, I've never been able to figure out how to set up something like this in a script or program I've worked on.  Since I mostly program in Ruby, can I setup something like a certain key press stops the program?  Every time I've looked into doing something similar, I always end up getting hung up when it comes to user input, whether that is a loop waiting for a condition, or something like this:

```
def Break()
  user_break = gets.strip
end

def Main()
Function1()
Break()
Function2()
Break()
[...]
end
```

It seems and is incredibly bulky, and definitely isn't easily scaled up or down.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to read:

- [What happens in BASH when you do Ctrl-C (hint, it's not simply sending a SIGINT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624622/what-happens-in-bash-when-you-do-ctrl-c-hint-its-not-simply-sending-a-sigint).
- [How does Ctrl-C terminate a child process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108953/how-does-ctrl-c-terminate-a-child-process).

You question has already been explained here well.